# DriveInfo Class

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

How to I execute the following code in silverlight 3.

```
    DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();        
    foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives)
    {
       if (drive.IsReady)
       { }   
    }
```

As it is giving me error and when I try to add the reference for the system.IO I can't fine any reference for that Dll.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight is executing in the browser, and can execute on platforms as diverse as Windows, OSX, Linux, etc.

I'd be really surprised is something as low-level as drive info would operate as it would on a Windows native forms app.